Problem installing rgee in R studio on windows machine
I am trying to install rgee in Rstudio and I'm hitting a problem at start. I install rgee and run ee_install (py_env = "rgee") and I get the following errors. I follow the instructions and run ee_clean_pyenv(). It doesn't seem to do anything but I restart the session and run ee_install(py_env = "rgee") again and it just repeats the same issue. I have tried running simply ee_install() as well but that causes the same issue.
What is the best way to fix this issue?
> library(rgee)
> ee_install(py_env = "rgee") 
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── Python configuration used to create rgee ──
python:         C:/Users/Mike Williamson/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/Scripts/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/Mike Williamson/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python39.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/Mike Williamson/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate
version:        3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/Mike Williamson/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  2.0.2
ee:             [NOT FOUND]
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
1. Removing the previous Python Environment (rgee), if it exists ...
rgee not found 


2. Creating a Python Environment (rgee)
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  An error occur when ee_install was creating the Python Environment. Run ee_clean_pyenv() and restart the R session, before trying again.


I just ran the same code, and it installed on my Windows machine. Have you tried to update your Python version? I think it is more compatible with Python version > 3.10. Run python --version to check your version of Python. Also, consider updating R on your machine.

I've got in working on my Mac now but I get an error with ee.check() > ee_check()
◉  Python version
✔ [Ok] /Users/michaelwilliamson/.virtualenvs/rgee/bin/python v3.13
◉  Python packages:
✔ [Ok] numpy
✔ [Ok] earthengine-api
Error in if (!ee_current_version == ee_version()) { :
argument is of length zero
